# Importing tables into EF7 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have started working with a seed project that uses EF-7 and MVC-6. The project includes an initial database migration for the identities tables. This all seems to work fine.

I now want to bring in an existing database into the project so my first attempt was to script out the tables and run them into the database the scaffold them into the project however when I try the Model Class is not available.

Is this the correct approach and if so how do a make the model classes available for scaffolding?

If this is not the correct approach how do I make the original database available within the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot work simultaneously with code first tables and existing tables in the same context. Either EF is responsible for all the entities or none. If you need to work with an existing database, you need to create a different context for that purpose.

Comment: ok, I have added a second context for the existing tables and created a scaffold to one of the tables including a view. When I try to load the Index page for the view I get the following error: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.Models.MyApp_DBContext' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Controllers.AssetsController'.

Comment: Sounds like a dependency injection issue. That really has nothing to do with anything here. Perhaps you forgot to add whatever config is necessary for your DI container to know how to resolve `MyApp_DBContext`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the following to ConfigureServices in startup.cs:     services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ScanBak_DBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));